# Form validation after ajax request

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, validation

I'm using Rails 3.2 and I'm making my first Ajax request.

This is my code:

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html {
          redirect_to @post
        }
        format.js
      else
        format.html {
          render 'posts/show'
        }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

So, I understand that I return a js template.

So, question 1: Is really a good idea to use this approach instead the standard sending json / receiving json in a $.ajax call?

My create.js.erb:

```
$(".commentlist").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @comment)) %>");
```

Working perfectly.

But... how I validate the form? (Without ajax works perfectly).

I'm seeing that the js.erb is like the html.erb but with js instead of html (I still see this weird, I think that is easier to use controller.coffee, but I will learn this way too :)).

So question 2: How I validate ? I see that what I get in the ajax call is the entire html and my two action vars (@post and @comment).

Just that, I need to learn the Rails approach to do ajax :)

P.S: My _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for comment, :url => post_comments_path(comment.post), :remote => true do |f| %>
    <% if comment.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(comment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this comment from being added:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.text_field :url %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content %>
    </p>
    <p class="no-border">
      <%= f.submit "Post", :class => "button" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```